# What are the lead and free variables of the matrix in reduced row-echelon form?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The following matrix is in reduced row-echelon form:

$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0&1&-1\\0&1&0&0&0&2&\\0&0&1&1&0&0&\end{bmatrix}$

There is a ‘staircase-structure’ in this matrix. In theory, at all of the separate ‘stairs’, the ﬁrst nonzero element of the row equals 1. These elements represent the lead variables. The others represent the free variables. However, I am confused whether the fourth variable is a lead variable as well, considering it starts with a 1, but doesn't follow the staircase structure. I believe that the fifth and the sixth variable are free variables and that the first three variables are definitely lead variables. Could someone confirm this?

Comment: the fourth variable happens to have 1 in row 3, but that's not the leftmost 1 of row 3 so doesn't qualify. only first three are free. I'm assuming your matrix is not n augmented one where last col is right sides of equations.

Comment: It's up to you from my point of view: if you swap the order of the variables, you swap the corresponding columns. . So,  in practice, any three set of variables $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$, $(x_1,x_2,x_4)$ $(x_2, x_3, x_5)$ or $x_2,x_4,x_5)$ can be taken as lead variables.

Comment: This is indeed not an augmented matrix, since there's no line at the right. @Bernard, so it isn't possible for x1, x2, x3 and x4 to be lead variables?

Comment: Augmented or not, this matrix corresponds to a linear system? If this is the case, I only say that *in practice* you can choose the lead variables among a certain set, changing the order of the variables if necessary.

Comment: Yeah it does correspond to a linear system. Thanks for your answer.